# How to fix ~ subprocess.check_output already sent erros at Raspberry pi with Stretch und Py3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to call the printer shell command from my Python script.

In the shell I can do this with command:

```
lpr -d HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710 example.txt
```

I have CUPS installed. OS is Debian Stretch on Raspberry Pi.

Python code:

```py
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(
        ['lpr', '-d', 'HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710', 'example.txt']).decode('utf-8'),
        shell = True)
```

But it results only in errors, e.g. `returned non-zero exit status 1`. I know that it means the script can not find a string. I do not know how to fix it.

I've also tried this Python code:

```py
print(subprocess.Popoen(
        ['lpr', '-d', 'HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710', 'example.txt'],
        shell = True))
```

But I get only errors or nothing messages, but no printing, too

Comment: Your questions is hard to understand. Can you format properly and try to describe more precisely what your problem is? See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for my bad words, i hope its better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without specifying any extra [parameters](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lpr.1.html):

```py
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output('lpr example.txt', shell=True))
```

Comment: The Message, again :

'========================== RESTART: /home/pi/dr.py ========================== Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/dr.py", line 6, in <module>
     print(subprocess.check_output('lpr -d HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710 td.txt',
shell=True))
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
     **kwargs).stdout
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lpr -d HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710 td.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
>>> 
'

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

> `cmd = ['lpr td.txt'] #<- here ->#`
>
> add Standart-Printer with lpoptions - d <> in your Shell
>    lpr Parameter -o oder Path must directly insert like

```
 ['lpr -o fit.to-page Desktop/myPicture,jpg']
```

Comment: How did it work in the shell with `lpr -d HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710 example.txt` command then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - back to the roots:

i tried this:

```
Python Code: 
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['lpr', '-d', 'HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710', 'td.txt']

print("CMD ist :>".format(cmd))

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = proc.communicate(timeout=120)

print("\nProcess terminated whith code: {:}".format(proc.returncode))

print("\STDOUT:\n{:}\n".format(out.decode()))
print("\STDERR:\n{:}\n".format(err.decode()))
```

The Output was:

> CMD ist :>
>
> Process terminated whith code: 1 \STDOUT:
>
> \STDERR: lpr: Warning - "d" format modifier not supported - output may
>   not be correct. lpr: Fehler - Zugriff auf »HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710«
>   nicht möglich - Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

ok, it seemed, i have an user rights problem ?